# How can I make repeating transactions over a given interval? (time, blocks, or times replayed?)

Tags: client, json-rpc, contracts, recurring-payments

I want to make a recurring payment that is enforced by the blockchain and the scripting engine.

If I have the following fixed source address, funded with 100 BTC

```
 16UwLL9Risc3QfPqBUvKofHmBQ7wMtjvM
```

I want to pay the following address 10 BTC ten times, approximately once every N blocks or once a month.

```
 1BTCorgHwCg6u2YSAWKgS17qUad6kHmtQW   (The Bitcoin foundation)
```

What are some approaches I should take to accomplish a recurring payment like this?